# It is not possible to disable the password prompt on the lock screen on the Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos-monterey

There is a MacBook user who can't or won't remember passwords. Therefore, I checked all settings and disabled all password prompts. There is now no password prompt at login and screen saver. However, the password - that the user can't or won't remember - is still asked after the user unintentionally selected the option `Lock Screen` in the Apple menu or after pressing the keys <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> (see screenshot below). The lock screen appears without having to know the password. However, you need to know it to be able to use the computer again. I would like to disable this option to avoid accidental lockout. How can I achieve this?

I am not looking for any hints on which way the user should remember a password. Instead of a password, fingerprints should not be stored either. The user has no capabilities for unlocking via Apple Watch. Also, my question has nothing to do with the fact that the password is requested before installing new software. Without knowing the password, you are not locked out, you just can't install software.

In case there is no solution to my question, it follows that a MacBook is intended only for people who are willing and able to use passwords, fingerprints or Apple Watch. Moreover, there is a compulsion to use a password even if there is no content worth protecting. Not to mention the surprise that suddenly occurs when the administrator assumes he has turned off all password prompts.

The user has a Macbook Pro with Monterey 12.6. An example image you find below.

The problem was also explained [here](https://web.sas.upenn.edu/jasonrw/2018/06/14/remove-the-lock-screen-menu-option-in-macos-10-13-high-sierra/) for an older MacOS:

> Computer labs or classrooms that feature a multiuser setup are not appropriate for locking the desktop. The main reason why is because once the desktop is locked, the only one who can unlock it is the one who locked it in the first place. With classrooms and labs that person is long gone by the time the locked desktop becomes a problem.

[image]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be another method than unchecking "Require password". Do you confirm that it doesn't work?

Comment: @harrymc Yes. You can check by yourself. You will always be able to lock your computer by the menu or pressing the key combination.

Comment: @granularbastard Are you looking for a solution for this person?  Or are you trying to prove that Mac doesn't allow completely customizing/disabling security?

Comment: @rfportilla I wouldn't call it security if the user who doesn't know a password can himself lock out. I added a link and citation in the OP that explains the problem from the viewpoint of an administrator. I would call it a trap.

Comment: @granularbastard Locking yourself out is ALWAYS a risk with security.  If you lose the key to your house (equivalent to losing the password), I doubt you would call that a trap.  It would be carelessness.  Be fair to Apple.  They have to consider what does the least harm.  Making it easy to blanket disable security is probably not what most people really want.  Unfortunately, this doesn't help your situation.

Comment: @rfportilla Let's assume you turn off all password prompts in the settings. Now you live with the misconception that the password is never prompted. So there should at least be a hint that you can still lock yourself out without knowing the password. I take that as a misconstruction of the operating system.

Comment: @granularbastard I think you are oversimplifying the OS.  It's built with security in mind.  If there are corner cases where you can lock yourself out, it's oversight (and probably considered low priority).  I'm sure you still disagree.  That's ok.  Best wishes..

Answer (score 1):

If the user still has their password, they should go to System Preferences > Security and Privacy and untick Require Password. Then, enter the user's password. Have them register their finger for Touch ID, and they no longer need a password to login!

Comment: Alternatively, they can unlock with their Apple Watch if they have one.

Comment: That's not a solution. The user is always able to be locked out after clicking on ```Lock Screen```. Finger prints are not desired.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The OP was revised concerning the objections of @Serverman .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://web.sas.upenn.edu/jasonrw/2018/06/14/remove-the-lock-screen-menu-option-in-macos-10-13-high-sierra/

This is written for 10.13, however I believe the objects.xib file should still contain the Lock Screen option.

You would remove the lines containing the `Lock Screen` option and id tag `311` from `/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/StandardMenus.nib/objects.xib` using the steps in the link.

Comment: https://web.sas.upenn.edu/jasonrw/2018/06/14/remove-the-lock-screen-menu-option-in-macos-10-13-high-sierra/ this may interest you. It refers to High Sierra, but the options may live in the same objects.xib file on 12.6 - I'll edit answer to include

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There you read: "This procedure does not prevent someone from locking with the keyboard combo." But at least someone else also registered the problem. Could somebody check if it works for Monterey 12.6.?

Answer (score 0):

At least until macOS 10.12 High Sierra, it is perfectly possible to have a user without any password. Just go to System Preferences --> Users and groups --> Change password (just guessing the names here, I am on a non-english version). There, type the current password and just leave the fields for the new password blanks. Then, the user will be able to unlock his session just by pressing < ENTER >.

**IMPORTANT:** it's unclear if a password-less user can still perform administrative tasks. `sudo` in a Terminal won't work for instance. It's also unclear what happens if this user is the only one on the Mac (there are 5 users on my Mac, 2 of them without password). It is apparently possible to set again a password at any moment, and I'm pretty sure macOS wouldn't let suppressing the password if it had wrong consequences, but just in case: before removing the password I recommend you create a new user with administration privileges, that **you** will be able to use in any circumstance.